# Playwright: Running certain files parallel and others serial in

Tags: playwright

I've created a few tests for my project, some test need to be run async while others can run sync.

Currently the config file is set to run async.

I've set a test file which runs them in the correct order. I've imported all the tests that should run sync into a single file. And tried adding

```
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'parallel' })
```

This changes the whole test process to run in parallel.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to only execute certain test async and other sync. Does anyone have experience with this?

The reason I need it to run async for certain files is to log in and authenticate before continuing, also certain actions affect the layout of the whole UI (even in a different browser) and will mess up other tests screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PW runs all test in parallel by default. But there are options to serialize tests **per file**. You cannot have both paralel and serial tests in one file.

From the playwright docs about [Serial Mode](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#serial-mode)

> Serial mode
>
> You can annotate inter-dependent tests as serial. If one
> of the serial tests fails, all subsequent tests are skipped. All tests
> in a group are retried together.

```js
import { test, Page } from '@playwright/test';

// Annotate entire file as serial.
test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });

let page: Page;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => { page = await browser.newPage(); });
test.afterAll(async () => { await page.close(); });

test('runs first', async () => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
});

test('runs second', async () => {
  await page.getByText('Get Started').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `await test.step('',{});` this allows you to run some tests asynchronously while steps are executed in order within the test (note there is `await` before each `test.step` )

```js
import { test,expect } from '@playwright/test';

let page;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => { page = await browser.newPage(); });
test.afterAll(async () => { await page.close(); });

test('Async test 1', async () => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/community/welcome');
  let heading = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Welcome' });
  await expect(heading).toBeVisible();

});

test('Async test 2', async () => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-playwright');
  let heading = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Playwright Library' });
  await expect(heading).toBeVisible();
});

test('Steps are executed synchronously', async () => {
  await test.step('Step 1', async () => {
      await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  });

  await test.step('Step 2', async () => {
      await page.getByText('Get Started').click();
  });

  await test.step('Step 3', async () => {
      let heading = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Installation' });
      await expect(heading).toBeVisible();
  });


});
```

See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-step